# rsync - Operation not permitted when script is launched by cron

Tags: macos, bash, rsync, cron

I've got a script that basically launches the following command

```
rsync -avh --progress --no-relative "$SOURCE_PATH/" "$DESTINATION_PATH"
```

and vice-versa (destination to source). Whenever I launch the script manually via terminal, it runs correctly; but when the cron launches the script, I get the error

```
rsync: opendir "foo/bar" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
```

The two paths are on not external volumes and are within the user's folder.

How should I set the permissions, if that's the problem?

Comment: Just curious, does it work if you use full paths instead of variables as your paths? Failing that can't think of anything else besides maybe it could be a user account permissions issue? Could check this with an `ls -la` on the directories involved.

Comment: The variables are actually initialized with the full paths involved.
I've got 'drwxr-xr-x' on both the folders

Comment: Depending on where the files are in the home directory, you may be running into the privacy protection system TCC ("Transparency, Consent, and Control"), which is completely separate from regular file permissions. See the Ask Different questions ["What and how does macOS Mojave implement to restrict applications access to personal data?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers) and ["Crontab Operation not permitted"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378553/crontab-operation-not-permitted).

Answer (score 0):

Solved by granting disk full access to cron.